# Rewrite query string in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i've searched for this for couple hours before posting the question...

I need to use .htaccess to transform urls that contain /go/[any_filename.mp3]?track into /track.php?[any_filename.mp3]

so, for example, input would be:

http://example.com/go/demo.mp3?track

user gets redirected to

http://example.com/track.php?demo.mp3

the /go directory is actually something i reserved to do this trick, so there's nothing actually there.  The current `.htaccess` configuration is

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please show us what you got so far.

Comment: @nietonfir 

my current .htaccess has the following entries. I'm using this to avoid putting the .php in url. so http://example.com/track?demo.mp3 would be redirected to http://example.com/track.php?demo.mp3

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: A question edit would've been a lot more helpfuller, don't you think. ;-)

Comment: sorry, first time here =/

Comment: No problem at all, that's why I mentioned it. Would you be so kind and update the question then please? That would be very nice for future references. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^track$ 
RewriteRule ^go/([^/.]+\.mp3)$ /track.php?$1 [L,R]
```